# How do I calculate the length of a string which holds a formatted decimal number

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsformatter

I am trying to calculate the number of characters in an `NSString` which has been formatted from decimal numbers with localisation.

Using the code below, I get the lengths correctly in UK localisation.  But it screws up if I try a French regional format, where the thousands seperator is a space and the decimal point is a comma.

Can anyone advise on the correct approach?

Here is the bit that should give me the number of characters:

```
-(NSString*)setFormatLength:(double)result;
{
    NSNumber* aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:result ];
    NSString* lengthcalc =[unformatter stringFromNumber: aNumber] ;
    int lnth = lengthcalc.length;
    NSLog(@" length %d",lnth);

    if(lnth == 15)
    {
      //do something
    }
    else
    {
    // do something else
    }

    return displayresult;
```

Here is the unformatter:

```
unformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[unformatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[unformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[unformatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[unformatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it screws up?" Does `lengthcalc.length` not return the number of characters in the string? Why is 15 a magical number here?

Comment: Yes, I think there is some confusion here over what you mean by "length". Perhaps update your question? The number of digits in the string? Or the actual character length of the string?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am trying to establish how many digits are in the string lengthcalc including any symbols like , or . representing grouping and decimal separators. the intention being to display the output in diffrent ways based on the number of digits in the string.

Comment: my nsnumber might be 1234579.12345678 in this case the length will be greater than 15 digits and so i will format this for display using scientific format but if the number 123.456 then i will display this in a diffrent way. my problen is that the string returned from the unformatter does not contain the expected number of digits. for example the nsnumber is 115746.4030778547 but the string returned is 115746,403 and so the lnth is 10 which is not what i expect - i want to see 17 as the lnth